# php.ini upload_max_filesize not updating

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm running CentOS 6.4. I've made changed to my php.ini file in the /etc folder. I have changed the upload_max_filesize from 2M to 50M so it reads:

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

I've also changed the post_max_size to 52M so it reads:

```
post_max_size = 52M
```

Now I have restarted Apache using both the service httpd restart command and the /sbin/service command but when I go into my root html directory in /var/www/html and open my test phpinfo() file the values for upload_max_filesize and post_max_filesize are still the default 2M and 8M values respectively.

Have I missed something?

Comment: mmm did you save the changes?

Comment: @kraysak yes when I open the file again the changes are still within the file its not reverted back to the defaults the phpinfo() is showing

Comment: check the phpinfo to make sure you are editing the correct php.ini. if you have suhosin, you must also change suhosin.post.max_value_length

Comment: ahhh so you are editing a wrong file...

Comment: @kraysak No its definitely the correct file im editing as the Loaded Configuration File in the phpinfo() points to /etc/php.ini which is the file im editing on the server.

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 nice thought but no I don't have suhosin installed

Comment: mmm... try to make another minor change, i don't know, disable some library, lyke GD and check it in the phpinfo()... but this maybe wont work

Comment: rename the php.ini and restart the service to see if it bombs.. if not, something has it cached

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 ok I renamed the php.ini file and restarted Apache. Now in the Loaded Configuration File it says (none),  php seems to still be running fine and the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are still at the default values.

Comment: you renamed php.ini and restarted apache, and the phpinfo still works?

Comment: @kraysak yes it just had a value of '(none)' in the 'Loaded Configuration File' part of the phpinfo()

Comment: did you renamed to php.ini and restarted apache again?

Comment: yes i renamed it, restarted apache checked the phpinfo() and the 'Loaded Configuration File' said (none). I then changed the name back to php.ini, restarted Apache and the 'Loaded Configuration File' was back to /etc/php.ini as expected but still holding the default vales.

Comment: @kraysak I've also carried out a complete reboot of the server and still its holding the default values even though the php.ini has definitely got the new values saved and the phpinfo() is pointing to the correct php.ini file /etc/php.ini

Comment: is very weird.. i dont know how i can help you, a lot of time i didn't use some unix/linux SO.. in your case i would try to reinstall php..

Comment: look htaccess.. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Answer (score 32):

I had to do this.

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Comment: You may need to run ```service --status-all``` to see the correct fpm version, as mine required ```sudo service php7.4-fpm restart```

Comment: This is the right answer. Almost for PHP 7.3 in Centos 8

Answer (score 19):

The latest php versions doesn't allow direct php.ini changes.

1. Look for "Scan this dir for additional .ini files" directory in your phpinfo() output and create whatever-file-name.ini in this location.
2. Put your custom variables in it.
3. Restart the webserver.

Comment: Odd, but works, on my php.ini I had made the change and restarted the server, but the default 2mb was still appearing on phpinfo. Creating a custom php.ini and putting my vars there worked.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly.

For me, the file was located in the directory `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d`

Comment: ^ THISSSSSSSSSSSS

Answer (score 3):

check the loading configuration file (php.ini) from the o/p of phpinfo(). Make sure that you have made changes in the right configuration file (php.ini file)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

The following changes fixed the issue.

1. Open phpinfo() and look for "Loaded Configuration File", this file should be updated.
2. Update your php.ini file.
3. Kill "php-fpm" process

> `killall php-fpm`

4. Restart httpd

> `systemctl restart httpd`

Answer (score 2):

I had this line uncommented, it needs to be commented `Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED` in php.ini

After that I could edit any value. And of course restart your apache

Answer (score 1):

In my case `sudo service apache2 restart` applied the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file, don't have any errors. php.ini don't set any configuration after error line.

Answer (score 0):

I have set the following values in .htaccess and it's working fine.
(I wanted to upload 25 MB file)

```
php_value post_max_size 30M
php_value upload_max_filesize 25M
php_value upload_max_size 25M
```